# Mixing asmx with CodeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I wish to include version information in an asmx file (as opposed to a web.config) such that I can edit the version number without recompiling.  Is there a clean way to accomplish this?  I did come up with a way to do it, but it's pretty horrifying:

WS.asmx:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="SiteWS.asmx.cs" Class="SiteWS" %>
```

WS.asmx.cs

```
public class SiteWS : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public static string WSVersion = "1.0";
}
```

---

New WS.asmx:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="SiteWS.asmx.cs" Class="SiteWS2" %>    
public class SiteWS2 : SiteWS
{
    static SiteWS2()
    {
        SiteWS.WSVersion = "1.0";
    }
}
```

New WS.asmx.cs

```
public class SiteWS : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public static string WSVersion = null;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that for?

Comment: @ChrisBint: The number corresponds to the version number of an exe.  If a new exe is released, it would be nice to be able to just edit an asmx file and upload an exe, rather than performing a recompile when in the middle of working on code.  Sure, one could instead shelve the current work and recompile the last version from version control, but this is simpler.  Doing unnecessary full rollouts is something to be avoided.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I mean why would you not just store this in the web.config. Seems a little bit like a hack when web.config is perfectly suited to store 'configuration' information like this.

Comment: @ChrisBint: This service is in the root of my site (it probably shouldn't be, but I'm not changing it now).  I don't want to stuff more junk into the root web.config file; it's unwieldy enough as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Its looks quite interesting about your concept.

Yes, If we place version information in **web.config**, whenever we touch **web.config** then it go for re-compiling.

I think, we should handle version information in two ways:-

1. primary in **`web.config`**
2. override of **`web.config`**, should be on **.asmx** file

So based on requirements, we can think where we need to set the version information.

Comment: web.config wouldn't require *me* to recompile the site.  I just don't want this information in the web.config at all.  Anyhow, this doesn't really answer my question.